# Android 8.1 emulator not able show dialog Properly

Tags: android, android-emulator

android emulator show dialog on statusbar in ubuntu 18

[image: First Screen]

[image: Second Screen]

Comment: Thanks for improving your question. This isn't a programming question, though.

Comment: Please post some code along with your question.

Comment: all app in emulator not able show dialog properly

Comment: create a new emulator